# Can you combine inlined values with AutoData in AutoFixture?

Tags: c#, autofixture

I'm using NUnit3 and AutoFixture with `AutoDataAttribute` as shown below:

```
[Test, AutoData]
public async Task Should_Filter_By_Date_Range_Only(Generator<AbpAuditLogs> generator)
{
    var startDate = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
    var endDate = new DateTime(2018, 1, 1);
    var logs = generator.Take(20).ToList();
    logs[5].ExecutionTime = GetRandomDateBetween(startDate, endDate);
}
```

How can I supply data coming from inline values combined with auto-generated data coming from AutoFixture?

```
// Pseudo-code
// TestCase(1, 2, <some auto generated list here>)
```

Comment: There are composite Data Attributes for xUnit - have a look at source to see if similar for NUnit http://blog.nikosbaxevanis.com/2012/07/27/composite-xunit-net-data-attributes/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look at the `InlineAutoDataAttribute`. Some AutoFixture with NUnit3 examples can be found [here](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/0708678d4d19dea9168231ccf3dcd14a08334362/Src/AutoFixture.NUnit3.UnitTest/Scenario.cs#L334-L377).

Comment: Take a look here https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1271677/FakeItEasy-AutoData-and-InlineAutoData

Comment: Also here https://blog.nikosbaxevanis.com/2012/07/31/autofixture-xunit-net-and-auto-mocking/